# Send email with magento

Tags: magento-1.8, email, email-templates

I'm using mandrill to send all transactional email's from my magento site but it only sends the emails that are allowed from the extension can I some how send any new created email I have tried with this code but didn't work for me any help please

```
<?php
    try {
        $mandrill = new Mandrill('YOUR_API_KEY');
        $message = array(
            'html' => '<p>Example HTML content</p>',
            'text' => 'Example text content',
            'subject' => 'example subject',
            'from_email' => 'message.from_email@example.com',
            'from_name' => 'Example Name',
            'to' => array(
                array(
                    'email' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
                    'name' => 'Recipient Name'
                )
            ),
            'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'message.reply@example.com'),
            'important' => false,
            'track_opens' => null,
            'track_clicks' => null,
            'auto_text' => null,
            'auto_html' => null,
            'inline_css' => null,
            'url_strip_qs' => null,
            'preserve_recipients' => null,
            'view_content_link' => null,
            'bcc_address' => 'message.bcc_address@example.com',
            'tracking_domain' => null,
            'signing_domain' => null,
            'return_path_domain' => null,
            'merge' => true,
            'global_merge_vars' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'merge1',
                    'content' => 'merge1 content'
                )
            ),
            'merge_vars' => array(
                array(
                    'rcpt' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
                    'vars' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'merge2',
                            'content' => 'merge2 content'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            'tags' => array('password-resets'),
            'subaccount' => 'customer-123',
            'google_analytics_domains' => array('example.com'),
            'google_analytics_campaign' => 'message.from_email@example.com',
            'metadata' => array('website' => 'www.example.com'),
            'recipient_metadata' => array(
                array(
                    'rcpt' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
                    'values' => array('user_id' => 123456)
                )
            ),
            'attachments' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text/plain',
                    'name' => 'myfile.txt',
                    'content' => 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl'
                )
            ),
            'images' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'image/png',
                    'name' => 'IMAGECID',
                    'content' => 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl'
                )
            )
        );
        $async = false;
        $ip_pool = 'Main Pool';
        $send_at = 'example send_at';
        $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
        print_r($result);

    } catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
        echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();

        throw $e;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: What's actually it has to do with Magento?

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this whit this code

```
$config = array('ssl' => 'tls', 'port' => 587, 'auth' => 'login', 'username' => 'webmaster@mydomain.com', 'password' => 'password');

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('mail.server.com', $config);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('This is the text of the mail.');
$mail->setFrom('sender@test.com', 'Some Sender');
$mail->addTo('recipient@test.com', 'Some Recipient');
$mail->setSubject('TestSubject');
$mail->send($transport);
```